# How do I duplicate my Heroku app to add to a pipeline?

Tags: heroku

I'm beginning to understand how Heroku works, but haven't yet used a pipeline. I have an app I'm working on that is near its first production version. I'd like to begin using pipelines.

But I don't understand how to begin. What do I need to do to make a copy of the current app and have that copy be in the development stage and make another copy for the staging stage? Do I fork my git repository twice and add each one?

I'm trying to take this one step at a time. I don't need GitHub integration yet. This is a small project and will not have any pull requests for quite some time, if ever. I'm only interested in the ability to develop, stage and release in the three stages offered by Heroku.

Comment: All your builds are best from master branch. Single repository. Just a personal preference. Use environment variables in your app to differentiate your dev, test, and/or prod environments. This is without using Heroku, just common knowledge of how the pipeline works best. Even in traditional Configuration Management sense, the same configuration item is moved through environments... it should not change other than environment variables. Doing everything from master prevents unnecessary code variability.

Comment: Of course you’ll still have development and feature branches, but all environment builds for release from master.

Comment: I currently have just one repository with a single master branch that I've been using to publish to Heroku. I guess I need to link that single create other pipeline branches and link those to separate Heroku apps and then link those apps to pipeline stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While pipelines do use multiple apps, they should use the same git repository with different remotes. [Heroku's help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) helped me understand that the process is to link the repository to each app different remote names and then push to the remote that I'm currently working on.